# How can I change the schema name and table name of a table in Databricks with Unity Catalog enabled?

Tags: databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

I have a table, located at `my_catalog.my_schema.my_table` in Databricks (version 13.3 LTS) with Unity Catalog enabled.

How can I rename this table to `my_catalog.my_new_schema.my_new_table` without doing a full table scan and a full copy? I want to do this as a metadata change without really going over the full data, because the table is huge.

I've tried the following:

```sql
ALTER TABLE my_catalog.my_schema.my_table RENAME TO my_catalog.my_new_schema.my_new_table
```

but this results in the following error:

> [CANNOT_RENAME_ACROSS_SCHEMA] Renaming a table across schemas is not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use renaming in order to move table from one catalog (or schema) to another. That would cause moving all the files from one location to another. If you want to do that you will need to do deep clone of source table and once clone is done remove old table.

Renaming in same catalog is possible with:

```sql
USE my_catalog.my_schema;
ALTER TABLE my_table RENAME TO my_new_table;
```

Comment: Hmmm, doing this gives me the same error message: `
[CANNOT_RENAME_ACROSS_SCHEMA] Renaming a table across schemas is not allowed.`. In which version of Databricks are you running this?

Comment: Sorry, it is probably connected to fact that it doesn't allow using fully qualified table name in this query. Try with: `USE my_catalog.my_schema; ALTER TABLE my_table RENAME TO my_new_table;`

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that... Still getting those errors. It seems like Databricks really does not allow moving a table from one schema to another. Sounds like such a basic operation but somehow this does not work or I'm doing stupid things :D

Comment: Well it doesn't allow moving from one schema to another, you can only rename table in same schema. It wouldn't be renaming as location where these tables are kept is in different place, so it would be copying all files basically.

Comment: Yeah I feared that... Would you agree that the answer to my question is "It's not possible to do that without doing a full table scan" then?

Comment: Yeah, edited response.

Comment: In your last answer update, I guess you mean it's not possible to move data from one schema to another? I'm staying in the same catalog, but trying to move from one schema to another.

Answer (score 1):

Is this an external table or a managed table? If it's external, then you can drop the table in one schema and create it (specifying the location) in the other schema. No scans or rewrites necessary. The data's location will not change, just the reference.

If this is a managed table, I don't believe it's possible to move between schemas/catalogs without rewriting the data.

Comment: Good catch! I was talking about a managed table. Had to fully rewrite it...